# IFNULL on query

Tags: mysql, sql

In the query below, I would like to make the "Percent" value `0` when it is `NULL`. However, I can't seem to figure out how to wrap the `IFNULL` function into my query properly. Any help would be appreciated!

```
SELECT number, ((DATEDIFF (scheduled_start_date,gate_3_start_date) - DATEDIFF (scheduled_due_date,gate_4_delivery_date))*100 / (DATEDIFF (scheduled_due_date,gate_4_delivery_date))) as 'Percent' FROM dashboard
```

Comment: `SELECT number, IFNULL((<your calculations>), 0) AS percent`

Answer (score 0):

Use MySql's coalesce

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

it should work for you. I can provide an example if you need it.